# C# object called in VB - "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference."

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am receiving the "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference." error when I try to call a struct in C# from VB.net.

I am writing the VB side of this, the C# side was previously written.
I have setup the reference to the C# project in my solution and can see everything from the C# project just fine.

Code I am calling

```
public ContourPt[] CalcContour(
            double LatDegr,
            double LonDegr,
            int NPts,
            double dBuBaseline,
            double ERP,
            double AntHAMSL,
            WHICHCHART_ENUM WhichChart,
            double AntAz,
            int AntennaId)
        {

            double dBu = dBuBaseline + 9.0 - 10.0 * Math.Log10(ERP / 1000.0);

            if(NPts < MinNPts) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("NPts", NPts, "must be at least "+MinNPts);
            double dAz = 360.0 / (double)NPts;


            LatLonDegr llDegr = new LatLonDegr(LatDegr, LonDegr);
            LatLonSec llSec = llDegr;
            return CalcContour(llSec.LatSecN, llSec.LonSecW, dAz, dBu, AntHAMSL, WhichChart, AntAz, AntennaId);
        }
```

I've tried mutiple ways of calling the method but I am consistenly getting the same error. But even the simple snippet below won't work.

```
Dim np() As ContourPt
np(i) = CalcContour(plat, plon, nPts, ddBu, dERP, dAnthAMSL, WhichChart, dAntAz, iAntId)
```

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.  If I need to provide additional code to better help solve the issue I have, please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: You're trying to call a function that presumably is an instance method on a class (but you don't show the class code), but your sample calling code does not show you new'ing up that class.

Comment: yup,   Dim np() As  new ContourPt should work

Comment: @Maertin np is the array that is holding the results.  It's not the class that has the calculation in it.  (Or at least there's no evidence of that)

Comment: @Kyle W thank you for pointing that out. The code may be failing at calls to LatLonDegr and LatLonSec also. Also the return statement at end seems to be an infinite loop.

Comment: @Maertin What makes you think the code is failing there?  Also, the return statement is calling a function with 8 parameters, so not calling itself.

Comment: Did you try [searching first](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Reference+to+a+non-shared+member+requires+an+object+reference)? You might have been able to find questions and answers on this site for this problem.

Comment: @Kyle W Good catch regarding 8 parameters. He did say he was able to get the calls to the objects working in his code. His error is a run-time error - meaning the chances are the error is with an object within the function. 'failing at calls to LatLonDegr and LatLonSec ' is just a guess on my part from the code he put.

Comment: @Maertin Where are you seeing that it's a run-time error? I see no such text.

Comment: @Kyle W My bad. It seems to be a compile-time error.

Comment: Thank you all.  The class is too large to post here, which is why i just showed the method that is causing me headaches.  I will work with instantiating the class and see if that works.  I had an Imports statement for the class in the VB module, but did not instantiate it specifically within the function.

Comment: `CalcContour` is not a Shared method therefore you must create an instance of the class that contains that method and then call it:  `Dim obj As New ClassName   np(i) = obj.CalcContour(...)`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the function itself needs to be declared `static`, so that it can be called without an object reference.

```
public static ContourPt[] CalcContour(...)
```

If you can't change the definition of that, then you need an instance of whatever class it is in.

```
public class ClassName{ // Is this in the ContourPt class?
    public ContourPt[] CalcContour(...)
}

Dim obj = new ClassName()
Dim np() As ContourPt
np(i) = obj.CalcContour(...)
```

Comment: The caveat (for making `CalcContour` `static`) is that `MinNPts` would also need to be `static` if it is not currently (everything else seems to be a parameter or a local variable).

Comment: @crashmstr Sure, or a const.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that some of the code was written in C# and some in VB is irrelevant - It's all IL by the time it runs.

The error simply means that you can't call a non-shared member unless you have an object instance. You need to instantiate the object you wish to use before you can use it:

```
   Dim o As New Object
   o.toString()
```

As opposed to calling a shared member, which you do directly on the class:

```
   Convert.toInt16(someValue);
```